# Convert CSV file into hex file with batch

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, hex

I would like to view the Hexadecimal code from csv file, and try to write a batch file which can generate hexadecimal file from csv file under specific folder.

But I have idea how to do it.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: There should be no need to convert it, just so that you can view it. I would just use a text editor with a hex view menu option.

Answer (score 3):

The command `certutil -encodehex` allows to convert a file to hexadecimal.  Syntax is as follows:
`certutil -encodehex [-f] inputfile outputfile`
The `-f` parameter is optional and overwrites the output file.

So in your case it would be

```
pushd "C:\directory"
certutil -encodehex -f file.csv file.hex
popd
```